# Добавление данных в Google Таблицу на основании ответов в Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-forms

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь разобраться уже не первый день. Есть форма:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1Dsi9bVxs4oVOLg12AFZ_-xKsS4kCdTcVFt1Rrtv3H7sgUw/viewform

И есть таблица:[image: Таблица музыка]
Нужно написать скрипт, который в момент, когда человек отправляет форму с выбранным спортзалом и трэками анализирует полученный ответ и ставит в моей таблице на пересечении выбранного спортзала и трэка - "1".
Я смог понять, как и где получить ответы:

```
function onFormSubmit(event){
 var form = FormApp.openById('1j7pBSqQjvBx3DGCf-2if42-czjsstg9Rq3SbXQoyzzg');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses(); 
  var LastResponse= formResponses.length;
   var formResponse  = formResponses[0];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log(LastResponse.toString(),
                itemResponses.length.toString(),
       itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
                itemResponse.getResponse());
  }
 }
```

Пока просто оно их выводит в логи. 
Моя проблема, что я не могу разобраться какими функциями прийти к моей таблице и нужному листу,
После чего сделать цикл, который:
Сначала берёт первый ответ и сверяем его с первой строкой таблицы, когда находит совпадение, то запоминает номер столбца.
Потом цикл в цикл, берём первый трэк и сравниваем его со столбцом трэков (столобец А), когда находим соответствие, то запоминаем номер строки, после чего сразу берём ранее записанное значение столбца и только что найденное значение строки и пишем в данную ячейку "1", после чего цикл проделывает аналогичную операцию с оставшимися 3-мя ответами (названиями трэков).

Буду очень признателен, если хоть чем-то подскажите, т.к. я понимаю, что простить написать скрипт это слишком много, буду стараться сам разобраться.

Comment: Вам не кажется это несколько сложным? Списки большие. Неюзабилити. Это ваше ТЗ про приложение в две колонки было недавно на какой-то бирже? Если вас устроит решение на базе Таблицы, то могу реализовать как web app http://bit.ly/rudriveorder

Answer (score 0):

Так а нужна именно такая последовательность действий? А если такой вариант:

1) Всякую форму можно привязать к таблице ответов
Например вот такая форма:

[image: Форма]

Дает такие ответы в таблицу:

[image: таблица]

Притом таблицу можете привязать любую - хоть эту же самую (на отдельной вкладке)

А затем, если у вас названия треков и спортзалов полностью идентичное с таблицей, можете либо живыми формулами, либо скриптами (триггерами как угодно) просчитать все с помощью COUNTIFS (СЧЕТЕСЛИМН)